# mailx command by specifying replyto list

Tags: linux, email

I am running a python script in my linux PC and use 'mailx' command to send email when script fails. The command is as mentioned below,

```
os.system(" mailx -a 'Content-Type: text/html' -s 'Failure: Log script status' abc@domain.com def@domain.com < ../report/log_output.html")
```

In this case user 'abc' & 'def' gets email in his outlook client with sender as

```
Alert User <alertuser@x26611-testbuntu04.unassigned-domain>
```

(which is a dummy email).
When any of the user try to do reply all, it will send a copy to

```
Alert User <alertuser@x26611-testbuntu04.unassigned-domain>
```

as well. I dont want this to happen. 
How can I write mailx command by specifying my own *Reply-To* email list while sending script failure email itself.

I am using below,
`Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-135-generic x86_64)`
&

**Edited**

`$ dpkg -s mailutils
Package: mailutils
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: mail
Installed-Size: 1674
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1:2.99.98-1.1
Provides: mail-reader, mailx`

Comment: Not really a programming question. The features of `mailx` vary from platform to platform, so you really need to be specific about which Linux distro you're on, and probably just consult the local `man` page to see if you can supply a `Reply-To:` header or perhaps an arbitrary customer header where you can put your `Reply-To:`

Comment: Replying to a list of recipients is technically possible, but very rarely actually useful. Bounce messages and some types of replies will ignore this header anyway. Is there a way you can put an actually useful sender in the `From:` header and/or the envelope sender instead?

Comment: `man` was not having option to supply `Reply-To` I could solve this by putting an actually useful sender in the `From:` header

Comment: Ubuntu has two different `mailx` man pages, [heirloom-mailx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/heirloom-mailx.1.html) and [bsd-mailx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/bsd-mailx.1.html).  Neither of these superficially has a version number which agrees with what's in your question. The options you use suggest the BSD one. Can you figure out which package provided this binary with `dpkg -S` please?

Comment: ... And if that's correct, the `-a` option you are already using can be specified a second time with `-a 'Reply-to: you@example.com'`

Comment: Tangentially, you should replace `os.system()` with `subprocess.run()` or something along those lines, not urgently but eventually. Sending mail from within Python would certainly give you full control over the headers, but will require either an additional external wrapper library or a clunky bit of standard library boilerplate involving both `email` and `smtplib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the version of `mailx` you are using supports adding custom headers with the `-a` option like you already do with `-a 'Content-type: text/html'` then you can just supply it a second time with the header you want; `-a 'Reply-to: you@example.net'`

Relying on `mailx` is somewhat brittle and a huge portability problem because there are multiple incompatible `mailx` implementations in common use.